# PUT method working in MongoDB Compass but not in mongodb cluster

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

In the orders field of my **activeorder** collection of my database I am storing the id array of multiple documents of another collection. Now I am moving any id from the array to the orders field of another document in the activeorder collection and deleting it from the previous document. It's working when I'm using MongoDB Compass but when storing in cluster the ID I'm moving is getting deleted but not being added to another collection. I have been trying to resolve this for the past few days. But there is no way to tell if someone knows.

Here is my code

```js
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import userModel from "../../models/user";
import ActiveOrder from "../../models/active_order";
import Column from "../../models/column";

// Controller function to update the name in activeorders collection
export default async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const { activeOrderId, orderId, newName } = req.body;
  console.log("before save", activeOrderId, orderId, newName);

  try {
    // Retrieve the active order with the given ID
    const activeOrder = await ActiveOrder.findById(activeOrderId);

    if (!activeOrder) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: "Active order not found" });
    }

    // Remove the ID from the orders array of the active order
    activeOrder.orders = activeOrder.orders.filter(
      (order) => order.toString() !== orderId
    );

    // Search for an active order with the given name
    let existingOrder = await ActiveOrder.findOne({ name: newName });

    if (existingOrder) {
      // Add the ID to the orders array of the existing active order
      existingOrder.orders.push(orderId);
      await existingOrder.save();
    } else {
      // Create a new active order with the given name and orders array
      existingOrder = new ActiveOrder({
        name: newName,
        user: activeOrder.user,
        orders: [orderId],
      });
      await existingOrder.save();
    }

    // Save the changes to the active order
    await activeOrder.save();
    console.log("after save", activeOrderId, orderId, newName);
    return res.status(200).json({ message: "Order updated successfully" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return res.status(500).json({ error: "Server error" });
  }
};
```

- [Image one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaqsW.png)
- [Image two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMd9h.png)

I want to remove the order id from the array and add to new one